# curl error : Warning: curl_exec(): 45 is not a valid cURL handle resource

Tags: php, curl

I was trying to fetch data from google search. I used the below code

```
$curl = curl_init();   
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/search?output=toolbar&q=".urlencode($fkey));  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
$contentstring = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
print $contentstring;
```

But its not displaying the page like below 
[image]

Please somebody help me to solve this... Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this code really from lines where error is? Second warning is two lines after firs and generated by `curl_error()` but in your code there is no line with `curl_error()`. And please attach those warnings as text not as images.

Comment: ya there is  if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
                                        {
                                            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
                                        } code which i didnt mensioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working pretty fine.

As you can see the image.. Google have blocked the request from your IP address as it detected unusual traffic activity.

You can always check the HTTP Status Code what your requesting URL gives by..

```
echo $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

If everything is normal , you would get a `200` response, else you will get some other status code.

Here are the most common HTTP Status Codes..

[image]

Comment: I see how this would result in the CAPTCHA content, but why is the cURL handle resource no longer valid after requesting this page? Is this documented behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
echo curl_error($curl) . ' (' . curl_errno($curl) . ')';
curl_close($curl);
```