# How to suppress error in get_headers() without using @

Tags: php

`get_headers()` throws a warning if the URL being checked is invalid. E.g.,

`get_headers('http://nonexistingrubbish-url.com');`

> Warning: get_headers(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Is it possible to suppress this error withou using `@`?

My main goal is to check whether a URL exist or not but I don't want to use the `@` suppressor.

Comment: you can disable php warning by using error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); or error_reporting(0); so you don't need to use @ sign. and to use with curl you can do something like curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

Comment: Use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) with the `CURLOPT_HEADER` and `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` options. (And maybe `CURLOPT_NOBODY` depending on what you want.)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with curl and it's not returning any warnings. If you use 'CURLOPT_NOBODY' then it will not try to download whole page.

```
<?php
$url = "http://nonexistingrubbish-url.com";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if ($result !== false) {
    $statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($statusCode == 404) {
        echo "URL Not Exists";
    } else {
        echo "URL Exists";
    }
} else {
    echo "URL not Exists";
}
```

Comment: IMO this is the best approach.

Comment: Perhaps it changed in recent versions but [Curl can apparently trigger warnings as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984964/curl-error-warning-curl-exec-45-is-not-a-valid-curl-handle-resource).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want it handled in such a way that doesn't interfere with your `error_reporting` and `log_errors` directives. The only way I can think of is writing a [custom error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). Here's an example from the PhpMailer library:

[Error handler](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/v6.0.1/src/SMTP.php#L1253):

```
/**
 * Reports an error number and string.
 *
 * @param int    $errno   The error number returned by PHP
 * @param string $errmsg  The error message returned by PHP
 * @param string $errfile The file the error occurred in
 * @param int    $errline The line number the error occurred on
 */
protected function errorHandler($errno, $errmsg, $errfile = '', $errline = 0)
{
    $notice = 'Connection failed.';
    $this->setError(
        $notice,
        $errmsg,
        (string) $errno
    );
    $this->edebug(
        "$notice Error #$errno: $errmsg [$errfile line $errline]",
        self::DEBUG_CONNECTION
    );
}
```

[Usage:](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/v6.0.1/src/SMTP.php#L398)

```
// Begin encrypted connection
set_error_handler([$this, 'errorHandler']);
$crypto_ok = stream_socket_enable_crypto(
    $this->smtp_conn,
    true,
    $crypto_method
);
restore_error_handler();
```

If necessary, there's always additional stuff to fine-tune either in the `set_error_handler()` call and the handler code itself. Here's another example from Guzzle that uses an anonymous function:

[Error handler and Usage:](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php#L233)

```
$errors = null;
set_error_handler(function ($_, $msg, $file, $line) use (&$errors) {
    $errors[] = [
        'message' => $msg,
        'file'    => $file,
        'line'    => $line
    ];
    return true;
});
$resource = $callback();
restore_error_handler();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the level of Error reporting before the function, reverting it after the function.

```
// Show all errors except warnings. 
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);
get_headers('http://nonexistingrubbish-url.com');
// revert to the above error reporting level. 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

---

> Why does this get a -1? This code works [on PHP 5.6.3] . Try it.

Code example (copy, upload and enjoy):

```
ini_set("display_errors",1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);
get_headers('http://nonexistingrubbish-url.com'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
get_headers('http://nonexistingrubbish-url.com'); 
print "<br><Br>done!";
```

This code will output only two error messages both relating to line 5. 
It will also output "done", below.